# Can someone help me with IIS and ODBC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have a problem with a 64 bit ODBC Source. I developed a simple website with a button. OnClick connect to a 64 bit ODBC Source. If I run this with the Visual Studio 2019, it works fine. But before I must change the Server Platform to 64 bit at properties/web Bitcount....

If I deploy the project to the localhost IIS. I do not get a connection.

I think the IIS do not work at 64 bit?

Yes it is a Windows 64bit platform. I tried it at a Windows 10 and a Windows 7 64bit platform. I do not configured the Application Pool. I tried the configuration at the advanced settings but i revoke it.

[image: This is the Option i changed]

> ************* Exception Text ************** System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException: ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver
>   Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
>   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection.HandleError(OdbcHandle hrHandle,
>   RetCode retcode)    at
>   System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnectionHandle..ctor(OdbcConnection connection,
>   OdbcConnectionString constr, OdbcEnvironmentHandle environmentHandle) 
>   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnectionOpen..ctor(OdbcConnection
>   outerConnection, OdbcConnectionString connectionOptions)    at
>   System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions
>   options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool,
>   DbConnection owningObject)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection)    at ….

Comment: Is your IIS platform Windows 64-bit? How do you have your Application Pool settings configured for your application? You can use the Advanced Settings to change an Application Pool from 64-bits to 32-bits.

Comment: "But before I must change the Server Platform to 64 bit at properties/web Bitcount...." What's that? Show some screenshots please, and don't others guess.

Comment: No connection? Can you provide log output or any error messages.

Comment: could you please share the detailed error message

Comment: What does your connection string look like? Do you have to create a DSN (using ODBC Data Source manager), or did you use a DSNless connection string? If you have to create a DSN, did you create it in 64bit version of ODBC Data Source Manager?

Comment: I created a User-DSN with the ODBC Data Source Manager. I tried it with both Manager. Nothing works